# App.XAML where are you?

Tags: wpf

I am new in WPF. Created a new WPF UserControl. See that some people uses an app.xaml file in order to set inside application level ressources.

My solution consists of a WinForm and a WPF UserControl. I don't see somewhere any app.xaml file.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

App.xaml is associated with a WPF application. If you've only got a UserControl, there's no application for it to be part of, is there?

Create a WPF application and you'll have an App.xaml to put application-level resources in.

Out of interest, why do you have WinForm if you're using a WPF user control?

EDIT: To repeat my comment: you're not going be provided with **WPF Application** resources smoothly when you're not creating a WPF application.

EDIT: As noted in Anthony Brien's answer, it seems you can hack it around - but I would strongly recommend *against* this sort of thing if you can possibly help it. Fundamentally, you're working against the expectations of the platform - and that's never a nice situation to be in.

Comment: because we think to fill an existing big WinForms application with WPF elements. We can't chage all the logic directly to WPF right now.

Comment: I'm actually hosting WPF user controls in a big winforms app which hopefully will become a full fledge WPF app. But if this is a new project, I fully agree with Jon Skeet

Comment: this is a demo application. But the scope of that demo is to demonstrate how a WinForm can host WPF controls. So in principle I can't change it to WPF one.

Comment: @serhio: In that case, you don't have a WPF application, so you don't have WPF-Application-level resources.

Comment: Ok, I'll use UserControl.Ressources instead of Application.Ressources.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Anthony Brien's answer solves the OP's question (and mine).  Your answer implies that it's not possible to use application scoped resources in a WinForms/WPF hybrid, which is not correct.

Comment: @EricJ.: Edited - but I'd still recommend against it.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to have application wide WPF resources in a WinForms application. Look at http://www.wpftutorial.net/AppLevelResourcesWinForms.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a WPF or Silverlight application to get that file
You are actually hosting a WPF control in a Winforms application

Comment: So, without a fully WPF application I have no acces at app.xaml, am I right?

Comment: If it's for a demo application, do you really really need it?

Comment: the scope of that demo is to demonstrate how a WinForm can host WPF controls. So in principle I can't change it to WPF one.

Comment: I did not mean to change the type of your application, but just to do without app.xaml

Answer (score 3):

If you created a WinForm project, it will not have a app.xaml.

Create a WPF project instead.

Answer (score 2):

This article explains in great detail how to have application wide resources in a hosted/interop scenario:

http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/05/managing-application-resources-when-wpf-is-hosted/

The solution path I chose (from the article) is to include App.xaml as a page element

Modify project file:

```
<Page Include="App.xaml" />
<Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Add code:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public static void EnsureApplicationResources()
{
    if (Application.Current == null)
    {
        // create the Application object
        new App();
    }
}
```

Full details are in the article.