# Style template for addin in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am designing a revit addin.I'm using WPF and I want to design style templates which can then be inherited by all WPF pages.I have read that I need to put the styles in app.xaml but there is no app.xaml as this is an addin.

As of now,I'm creating style templates but one template can only be used by the elements of that particular page.

I want to create a style template which every page can inherit without app.xaml.How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to share styles and maybe some resources you can do it without an App.xaml. In your project, create a xaml file to contain the shared styles and call it something like "MyCommonResources.xaml". It should simply contain a resource dictionary that holds the shared styles/resources. For example:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAppNS">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Window.Background" Color="#FF202020"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyTitleBar.Background" Color="#FF5A5A5A"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyTitleBar.Foreground" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyTitleBar.Disabled.Background" Color="Black"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyTitleBar.Disabled.Foreground" Color="Gray"/>

    <Style x:Key="CommandButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="40"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MyTitleBarStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MyTitleBar.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MyTitleBar.Foreground}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="34"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MyTitleBar.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MyTitleBar.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

now in your xaml for the Window/Page/UserControl add a resource section and merge this dictionary in with the local...

```
    <Window x:Class="MyAppNS.MyWPFWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAppNS"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="MyCommonResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <Style x:Key="MyLocalStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="This is the Title"
               Style="{StaticResource MyTitleBarStyle}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnOK" Grid.Row="1" Content="OK"
                Style="{StaticResource CommandButtonStyle}"
                Click="btnOK_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Excuse me for any typos in the above, cut & pasted it from a Winforms app I have but quickly edited it down so it wouldn't be so large and changed some names to make better sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a WPF project or just a WPF view in a Forms application?

Maybe this contribution will help you -> 
[App.XAML where are you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725945/app-xaml-where-are-you)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I'm afraid it didn't help me :(